# .Net core MsBuild UsinTask throws System.runtime version=4.1.0.0 or could not load file or one of its dependencies

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I am trying to register my own ms build task, but I am getting

The "MyTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly Path/TasksAssembly.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Does someone runed into this problem? Why does it search for System.Runtime 4.1.0.0?

In the dependencies of Microsoft.Build 15.1.1012 I am seeing System.Runtime 4.3.0.

Comment: What target framework does your task use?

Comment: @MartinUllrich netcoreapp1.1. All the projects in the solution use this framework.

Comment: Are you running the project? or using msbuild to load the assembly? for the latter one, you should use netstandard1.6 for the .net core version of msbuild and net461 for the full framework version.

Comment: I need msbuild to perform a simple replace, before build. 
I don't understand. Why should I target net461 and install netstandard 1.6? Isn't net 461 before .net core? And why netstandard 1.6 is needed in the project? My dependencies are ok, I don't need anything from netstandard library as all of the deps are present in the Microsoft.Build package. It just searches for the wrong version of System.Runtime for some reason.